# Is there a property in Qt-objects, which is used as default value property?

Tags: qt

I couldn't find out, how Qt selects the appropriate property for a widget mapped to a model using

```
QDataWidgetMapper::addMapping ( QWidget * widget, int section )
```

The docu (4.8) tells something about user property but which one?

In the examples the text property is used for a line edit, current-index for spin-box. Is there a property in Qt-objects, which is used as default value property? If so, than I'have missed something essential.

Comment: Yes, widgets usually have a user property. [`The USER attribute indicates whether the property is designated as the user-facing or user-editable property for the class. Normally, there is only one USER property per class (default false). e.g., QAbstractButton::checked is the user editable property for (checkable) buttons. Note that QItemDelegate gets and sets a widget's USER property.`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/properties.html#qt-s-property-system)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but [check this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html) note there some properties have a `RESET` methods to restore default value.

Comment: "user property but which one" There's only one, or none. There are multiple properties, and at most one of them can be declared to be the user property.

Comment: @KubaOber I missed that they mean the flag USER but thought, that any user-defined property is meant. Btw, is there a way to check which property is currently the user property in QObject, or is there a possibility to define the USER-property in run-time? Is the flag reset on the other property then?

Comment: The USER flag is set in the read-only part of the metadata IIRC, so it can't be changed after the code has been compiled.

Comment: cool, thanks! Very useful information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a QLineEdit, the text property is used, because QLineEdit is declared as follows:

```
class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QLineEdit : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString inputMask READ inputMask WRITE setInputMask)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString text READ text WRITE setText NOTIFY textChanged USER true)
    Q_PROPERTY(int maxLength READ maxLength WRITE setMaxLength)
    ...
```

Note that the Q_PROPERTY text has its USER property set to true. According to the documentation (http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/properties.html)

> The USER attribute indicates whether the property is designated as the user-facing or user-editable property for the class. Normally, there is only one USER property per class (default false). e.g., QAbstractButton::checked is the user editable property for (checkable) buttons. Note that QItemDelegate gets and sets a widget's USER property.